# How to collapse an expander

Tags: c#, wpf

C#-WPF
I'm trying to collapse an expander in a function, but I can't seem to find any method that does that.
Is there any way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should just be able to set the IsExpanded property on the expander control.

```
expander.IsExpanded = false;
```